# Radio-Box images in DrRacket

Tags: user-interface, racket

I am creating a mini-self project in DrRacket and I've come across an issue. What I want to do is create a champion and role selection phase for the game League of Legends. What I want to do is make it so that the role selections come up as pictures rather than strings in a radio-box. Is there a way to implement pictures in a radio-box or would I have to take an alternative approach? Here's my entire code for reference:

```
#lang racket/gui
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)
(define x 'decorative)

;champion list
(define champs_unsorted '("Sett" "Mordekaiser" "Darius" "Garen" "Rek'sai" "Hecarim" "Shaco" "Viego"       "Azir" "Zed" "Fizz" "Viktor" "Samira" "Caitlyn" "Aphelios" "Vayne" "Karma" "Blitzacrank" "Brand" "Pyke"))

(define champs (sort champs_unsorted string<?))

;main frame 
(define frame (new frame% [label "Champ Select"] [height 400]
               [stretchable-width #t]    
       [stretchable-height #t]
               [spacing 0]))
;menu
(define menu-bar (new menu-bar% [parent frame]))
;file menu
(define file-menu (new menu% [parent menu-bar] [label "File"]))
;exit menu
(define exit-menu (new menu-item% [parent file-menu] [label "Exit"]
                   [callback (lambda (menu-item event)
                               (send frame show #f))]))
                               
;panes
(define pane (new horizontal-pane% [parent frame] [horiz-margin 15]))
(define pane2 (new horizontal-pane% [parent frame] [horiz-margin 15]))
(define pane3(new horizontal-pane% [parent frame] [horiz-margin 15]))

;role images
(define roles '("path/to/topicon.png"))


;role box
(define role-choice (new radio-box% [parent pane]
                   [label "Role: "]
                   [style (list 'horizontal)]
                   [font (make-font #:size 10.5 #:family x #:weight 'bold)]
                   [choices roles]))
                   
                                 

;champ box                         
(define champ-choice (new choice% [parent pane2]
                     [label "Champion: "]
                     [font (make-font #:size 10.5 #:family x #:weight 'bold)]
                     [choices champs]
                     [vert-margin 0]
                     [horiz-margin 10]))
                 

;message assigned to role chosen
(define button-msg (lambda (role)
                 (match role                       
                   [0 (send result-msg set-label "Top Lane Chosen, Loading in... ")]
                   [1 (send result-msg set-label "Jungle Chosen, Loading in... ")]
                   [2 (send result-msg set-label "Mid Lane Chosen, Loading in... ")]
                   [3 (send result-msg set-label "ADC Chosen, Loading in... ")]
                   [4 (send result-msg set-label "Support Chosen, Loading in... ")]))) 

;button to lock in role
(define lock-in-button (new button% [parent pane3]
             [label "Lock in"]
             [vert-margin 0]
             [min-width 50]
             [min-height 20]
             [font (make-font #:size 11 #:family x #:weight 'bold)]
             [callback (lambda (button event)
                        (button-msg (send role-choice get-selection))
                         )]))
;message displayed once button is clicked
(define result-msg (new message% [parent pane3]
                   [label ""]
                   [font (make-font #:size 11 #:family x  #:weight 'bold)]
                   [min-width 600]
                   [horiz-margin 20]
                   [vert-margin 50]
                   ))

(send frame center 'both)
(send frame show #t)
```

[The code when ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QW2Vo.png)

Thank you!